# Which Ubuntu version that support HP 14-bw001au?

Tags: 14.04, windows-10, hp

I want to remove the Windows 10 from my laptop and switch to Ubuntu. But I am not sure which Ubuntu version that support the laptop.

The laptop is HP 14-bw001au.

Thank you.

Comment: We only have ONE hardware stack. What happend when you made a live Ubuntu DVD/USB and booted from it? It was made for exactly your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much that a particular version works better with particular hardware - generally hardware support improves slightly with each version, which includes both newer and older hardware.  Thus, there's no reason to use an older Ubuntu version to better support hardware.

Your choice of Ubuntu version should come down to a balance between frequent updates to software and less frequent updates.  LTS versions update every 2 years and support runs out after 5 years, while regular versions update every 6 months and support runs out after 9 months.

The current version (18.04) also happens to be an LTS version as well, so there is no reason not to install it and defer the choice of LTS or no-LTS until 18.10 comes out later this year.

Comment: When it comes to flavors (ie. kubuntu, lubuntu, xubuntu ubuntu-mate, ubu... etc) its really a personal preference as to which suits your tastes and workflow.  Yes some are lighter (use less resources) than others, but it's more just personal likes/dislikes (ie. you have to decide what's best for you & what you want to use the machine for)